# How to set navigation url for Text in DataGrid Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF window which is bound to a database. Database fields are `Link, Title, SavedOn` which have types `nvarchar, nvarchar and DateTime` respectively. At present all the feilds are bound to different columns in DataGrid. I am using `DataGridHyperLinkColumn` for Link column and `Event Setter` to capture `Hyperlink.Click` events. All is working fine.

**PROBLEM:**

But now i want to make it such a way that Text in `Title` Column of datagrid links to the `Link` that is when clicked takes me to the `Link`.Using this approach i'll save one column as both title and clickable link is in one column just as in normal webpages.Any ideas how can i go about this?. Currently grid looks like this:
 [image]

Plus, how can i change the default royal blue color of links to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ContentBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridhyperlinkcolumn.contentbinding.aspx) to specify the display text for the link (just get rid of the `Title` column).

> To display hyperlink text that is different than the URI string, use the **ContentBinding** property.

To style the hyperlinks in the whole grid add a style to the `DataGrid.Resources`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Lime" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

...to apply it only in one column assign it as the `ElementStyle` of the column, you will need to nest it in a `TextBlock` style though.

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                <!-- ... -->
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
```